# How to introduce assumption in lean4

Tags: lean4

This is probably a trivial question, but I've been googling for hours and can't find the syntax I'm looking for.

I'm trying to write a proof of

```
example (A B C : Prop) (h : A → (B ∨ C)) : (A → B) ∨ (A → C) := by
<logic goes here>
```

The logic I'm trying to replicate is something like:

- Assume `A`
- From `h` we have `B ∨ C`
- if `B`, then `A → B`, which implies `(A → B) ∨ (A → C)`
- conversely, if `¬B`, then `C`, so `A → C`, which again implies `(A → B) ∨ (A → C)`
- Finally, if `¬A`, then `A → B`, which implies `(A → B) ∨ (A → C)`

I assume this is what `cases` is for, but when I try `cases h` I'm told: *"tactic 'induction' failed, major premise type is not an inductive type"*

Comment: You seem to be doing classical reasoning.

Comment: @AgnishomChattopadhyay Correct. Since posting my question, I've figured out that I can introduce a tautology via "have hemA : A ∨ ¬A := em A" and then do cases on that. I think I have it mostly figured out, now. Will post my answer when I'm done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!

This might not be the most elegant solution, but it works.

```
open Classical

example (A B C : Prop) (h : A → (B ∨ C)) : ((A → B) ∨ (A → C)) := by
  have hemA : A ∨ ¬A := em A
  cases hemA
  {
    have hBC : B ∨ C := by 
      apply h
      assumption
    cases hBC
    {
      apply Or.inl
      intro
      assumption
    }
    {
      apply Or.inr
      intro
      assumption
    }
  }
  {
    have hAB : A → B := by
      intro
      contradiction
    apply Or.inl
    exact hAB
  }
```

More elegant solutions are of course welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Note that lean has good support for structured proofs:

````
open Classical

example (A B C : Prop) (h : A → (B ∨ C)) : ((A → B) ∨ (A → C)) := by
  cases em A with
  | inl ha =>
    cases h ha with
    | inl hb =>
      left
      intro
      exact hb
    | inr hc =>
      right
      intro
      exact hc
  | inr na => 
    apply Or.inl
    intro
    contradiction
```
````